# Load a web page in a div using iframe throwing Mixed Mode content Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-chrome-extension, mixed-content

I have created a chrome extension.
I am trying to render a eBay web page in the same browser in a div using an i frame inside the div element. I have set the source attribute url to be https then also I am getting an error of Mixed mode content

Ideally, it should open a web page in the div element. which it was doing previously. But, suddenly, it has stoped

I am getting an error of Mixed mode content. Even when I am sending as https request, it is converting to http. Please see attached file for the issue.

[Issue in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zco0r.png)

```
<div class="my-div">
<iframe id="my-iframe" src="https://offer.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?
ViewBidsLogin&item=222313350236&ViewBidsLogin=">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change `http` to `https` with the url `http://offer.ebay.com`? or you only changed to HTTPS for the URL `www.ebay.com`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.I have changed to https